# Could there be a reason why System.Type.ForName would take a lot of time to execute?

Tags: apex

I recently found after debugging that System.Type.ForName(namespace, dummyClass) is taking too much time to execute.

Can anyone tell me the inner working of System.Type.ForName method? Does it depend on the code written in dummyClass?

Comment: How much is "too much time"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: This question is very unlikely to get any concrete resolution on SFSE.

Comment: The command Type.ForName itself is not the issue.. Obviously it will depend on the code in dummy class, is it invoke its constructor....

Comment: It is taking from 15-30 seconds to execute. Example:
12:48:59.2 (4912820)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1200]||System.Type.forName(String, String)
12:49:14.367 (15367963819)|METHOD_EXIT|[1200]||System.Type.forName(String, String)

And there is no constructor written, so it has to be the default one.
There are 5 SOQL statements, huge data being parsed and a future method in this class. @sfdcfox Liron can any of these cause this huge execution time?

Comment: Also about 8-10 lists of DML.

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce has to "compile" the class, so if it's not in the code cache, it can take significant time. This should not happen frequently, except perhaps after deployments or maintenance periods. If you're getting consistently poor performance, consider opening a case with Technical Support. It should not ordinarily take more than a fraction of a second to compile the code under normal circumstances, although it does depend on the complexity of the class (e.g. how many other classes are referenced, etc).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. It refers many classes. If I reduce the references and code in single class, would it help? And it is a pretty complex class with lots of functionality.

Comment: @Divya Yes, the more classes you reference, the longer compilation takes. Note that this will likely only be a problem during development, as production compiles code on deployment, not during first reference.

Comment: Thanks for quick and insightful answer. This is disrupting testing so I'll definitely  try to remove references and try in sandbox.

Comment: @Divya Use the Compile All Classes before testing (Setup > Apex Classes > Compile All Classes) before testing. You'll get better results.

Comment: Personally I would NOT start refactoring code to speed things up (at least for this scenario - obviously improve badly written code that performs poorly!). As sfdcfox said, it should only happen in specific scenarios and, once done, be then cached for fast processing otherwise.

Comment: One more question, is there a way to cache code like we can cache most used records? Because I've noticed that this problem occurs 1-2 times a day (when we start executing the code for the first time in a day). Or is it just a weird coincidence?

Comment: @Divya That's actually pretty "normal." I suppose you could keep things fresh in the cache by setting up a scheduled job that periodically brings up the class so it's already pre-compiled if this is really an issue.